# How to follow another CSS selector's properties?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap CSS and I want my site to consistently use the same button design (class="`btn btn-primary`"). But there's a plugin I'm using that has its own class for buttons ("`ethpress-metamask-login-button`").

So, how could I make `ethpress-metamask-login-button` class to follow `btn btn-primary` properties other than copying each property over to `ethpress-metamask-login-button` declaration block?

Comment: cant you just apply the class to the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define your own styling for .btn.btn-primary, you could just extend the selector like this:

.btn.btn-primary, .ethpress-metamask-login-button {....}

If you are using SCSS/SASS you can use the @extend function

Or simply unset properties that are set by default for ethpress-metamask-login-button and add a class btn btn-primary to the HTML tag..

Comment: I'm using bootstrap's own CSS properties. Do I unset like this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

Comment: Yes, I usually inspect an element to see what properties it has assigned, then in my own css I either override them, or unset them.

Note: always try to avoid using !important